# concatenate path with values from db using php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to delete files from folder on server using values returned from db fields. The path includes `directory\[file_owner]\[file_name]` where values inside square brackets come from db fields.

this works where I have generated $_file_owner and $_file_name from a GET function

```
$file_path = '../uploads/user_'.$_file_owner.'/'. $_file_name;
```

but I should be able to get them directly from the POST value from the HTML/PHP form:

```
$file_path = '../uploads/user_' . $_POST["file_owner"] . '/' . $_POST["file_name"];
```

what am I doing wrong?

here is the HTML form code (inside fetch.php):

```
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id_files"].'" data-file_name="'.$row["file_name"].'">Delete</button></td>
```

and here is how it is called in the index.html js:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var file_owner = $(this).data("file_owner");
    var file_name = $(this).data("file_name");
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"delete.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, file_owner:file_owner, file_name:file_name},
    success:function(data)
    {
     load_file_data();
     alert("File removed");
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

in short the following:

```
$file_path = '../uploads/user_' . $_POST["file_owner"] . '/' . $_POST["file_name"];
```

should return:

```
../uploads/user_[file_owner]/file_name.ext
```

file_owner is a number - so, if I explicitly use say:

```
$file_path = '../uploads/user_3/' . $_POST["file_name"];
```

it works - therefore it looks like $_POST["file_owner"] is not being returned from the js inside the html form page - although it returns $_POST["file_name"] without problem

Comment: `GET` and `POST` are not the same thing. How are you setting your `$_file_owner` and `$_file_name` variables?

Comment: thanks Obsidian - here is how i am using a function to get the values from the db: ```function get_file_owner($connect, $id)
{
 $query = "
 SELECT file_owner FROM files WHERE id_files = '".$id."'
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  return $row["file_owner"];
 }
}``` then inside the ```if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 
 $temp_file_owner = get_file_owner($connect, $_POST["id"]);
 $_file_owner = $_POST["file_owner"]; ```

Comment: Edit the original question. Its a lot more readable that way.

Comment: Show us your HTML form code

Comment: have updated original post with extra detail